# Add items to the standard QWebView context menu

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4, contextmenu, qwebview

The implementation of QWebView has a standard context menu. I want to change it and create my own - or add "Open in new tab" to the standard context menu, and then connect it to my application. How to do it?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you show us some code?

Comment: Can you eplaine me what I can do after,  ...setContextMenuPolicy(0) (turnoff). How to Create new contextmenu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reimplement `QWebView.contextMenuEvent`:

```
class WebView(QtWebKit.QWebView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WebView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.newTabAction = QtGui.QAction('Open in new tab', self)
        self.newTabAction.triggered.connect(self.createNewTab)

    def createNewTab(self):
        url = self.newTabAction.data()
        print('create new tab:', url.toString())

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        menu = self.page().createStandardContextMenu()
        hit = self.page().currentFrame().hitTestContent(event.pos())
        url = hit.linkUrl()
        if url.isValid():
            self.newTabAction.setData(url)
            menu.addAction(self.newTabAction)
        menu.exec_(event.globalPos())
```

If you don't want to use the standard context menu, just use `QtGui.QMenu()` to create your own.

Comment: Thanks, it works on all web page. But I'd like only on hovered on links.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to use this successfully to implement a context menu for images (by replacing `linkUrl` with `imageUrl`).